# objective-c text colour

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm writing an application for the iPad that will tell us whether or not someone is on court at a tennis tournament. Basically, just an application with a list of names each with an on/off button next to them. Once the on button is pressed, their name turns red, thus they are on court.

How would I go about loading an excel list of names etc. with editable font colour that I can assign to a button?

thanks,
louis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Have a status column (1 or 0) beside each name in your excel file.
2. Export to CSV format.
3. Read in the file in your app. (There are many ways to do this: import into Xcode, download through web etc., depends on your needs.)
4. Parse the file (by using the return character and the separator character).
5. Set the color in your tableview according to the status.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, I'm not familiar with the term status column though. Could you explain please?